# C# code builder/formatter

Tags: c#, code-generation

Does anyone know of a library which helps with generating C# code? For example, if I need to generate a *.cs file containing the definition of a class, I'd like to be able to specify the class and method bodies using an object tree (similar to expression trees) and then tell the library to give me well the formatted C# code as a string.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, I want to call the library from custom C# code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at [`Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx)?

> Provides access to instances of the C# code generator and code compiler.

Comment: It sure is, it's part of System.dll.

Comment: +1 and I would like that with CodeDom you can target different languages with same codebase.

Comment: @Sasha - should have looked at what assembly it was in... thanks :)

Comment: I never realized that that provider goes both ways. I'll take a look at what it does.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for code generation and they are listed below:

Code Smith
codesmithtools dot com

codegeneratorpro dot com

etc

Code generators may sound like saving a lot of time, in reality it depends on the kind of project your working on.

Look into System.CodeDom and CSharpCodeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather fond of Terance Parr's [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/). It's at the core of the compiler building tool [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) — StringTemplate is responsible for for code generation, allowing ANTLR to target just about any language for its compilers.

You can download the latest C#/.Net port from http://www.stringtemplate.org/download.html

You can read about string template in these papers by Dr. Parr:

- [[DRAFT] A Functional Language For Generating Structured Text](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/ST.pdf)
- [Enforcing Strict Model-View Separation in Template Engines](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf)
- More at http://www.stringtemplate.org/article/list

CodeProject has an article on code generation with StringTemplate as well: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/DotNetCodeGeneration.aspx